# Maven SpringBoot JavaFx app run on IDE not on command prompt

Tags: spring-boot, maven, javafx, desktop

I am trying to build a JavaFX application using Spring Boot and maven, the app run perfectly on eclipse IDE, but not when i excute:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

the project is under JavaSE-17 (JDK 17.0.2), when i run the project from eclipse i add on VM argument of course:

```
--module-path C:\Users\piratack007\Desktop\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

otherwise it display on Eclipse IDE:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Now when i execute the project from command prompt i've got

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

How can i add JavaFx components from command prompt and run this spring boot project?

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectVetoBooksSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProjectVetoBooksSpringBoot</name>
    <description>VetoBooks App V1.0.0</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                 <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
             </dependency>
         
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
 
         
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
         
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
             <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
             <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
             <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>   
        </plugins>
        <!--<resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/resources</targetPath>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
         </resources>-->
        
    </build>
    <!--<profiles>
             <profile>
                      <id>default</id>
                      <activation>
                         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                      </activation>
                      <properties>
                            <database.driverClassName>org.sqlite.JDBC</database.driverClassName>
                            <database.url>jdbc:sqlite:/resources/db/database2.sqlite</database.url>
                      </properties>
              </profile>
     </profiles>-->

</project>
```

Comment: Don’t use `mvn spring-boot:run` to run your app.  Whatever command eclipse is using to run the app successfully in the IDE copy it and run the same command in your console.  In Idea this command is displayed in the execution console pane within the IDE and can be copied from there.  I don’t know if Eclipse will also do the same allowing you to easily copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java 11, JavaFX was removed from the SDK. It is now in its own separate module, and if we want to use it in our application from cmd using mvn spring-boot:run without --module-path and --add-modules, we will need to use jdk that contain JavaFx from command line like zulu fx jdk, and it's done.